# Resetting a timer in andengine

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have this class that I use to set a interval during the duration of my game.

```
public class Timer implements IUpdateHandler {
    // ===========================================================
    // Constants          
    // ===========================================================

    // ===========================================================          
    // Fields        
    // ===========================================================
    private ITimerCallback mCallback;
    private float mInterval;

    private float mSecondsElapsed;
    // ===========================================================          
    // Constructors          
    // ===========================================================
    public Timer(final float pInterval, final ITimerCallback pCallback) {
            this.mInterval = pInterval;
            this.mCallback = pCallback;
    }
    // ===========================================================          
    // Getter & Setter          
    // ===========================================================
    public void setInterval(final float pInterval) {
            this.mInterval = pInterval;
    }
    // ===========================================================          
    // Methods for/from SuperClass/Interfaces          
    // ===========================================================  
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            this.mSecondsElapsed += pSecondsElapsed;
            if(this.mSecondsElapsed >= this.mInterval) {
                    this.mSecondsElapsed -= this.mInterval;
                    this.mCallback.onTick();
            }
    }
    @Override
    public void reset() {
            this.mSecondsElapsed = 0;

    }
    // ===========================================================          
    // Methods          
    // ===========================================================  

    // ===========================================================          
    // Inner and Anonymous Classes          
    // ===========================================================
    public interface ITimerCallback {
            public void onTick();
    }
}
```

The problem is I need to find a way to pause it, or reset the time completely when I need to.

How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

That class has a reset() method for that purpose. If you want to pause it, you would likely want to add a private boolean to the class and create a pause() method to call - in the pause method set your paused boolean. Then modify the onUpdate() method and add an `if (!paused) { 
//do rest of onUpdate here
}`

You will also probably need an unPause() method - or just make a single method when you pass in the state you want, something like `setPause(boolean state) {}`